# How can I switch graphic card acceleration from sna to uxa?

Tags: graphics, xorg, intel-graphics

The `sna` acceleration is default option and I want to go back to `uxa` because sna doesn't work after suspending on my laptop.

And it doesn't work just adding `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` which contains

```
"Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection"
```

to make the switch.

After input: `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -ie uxa -ie sna` in terminal. The output is:

```
[     4.142] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.6 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[     4.144] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Broadwell backend
```

And it seems that the UXA is not compiled or installed at the beginning.

Is there a way to switch to UXA under this situation?

Comment: This (Hibernation-error) is rather related to the Linux-Kernel than to the graphics driver. Please give also details what card in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your configuration file (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`) has too much quotes.

Without surrounding quotes:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

The uxa acceleration method should be used.