# How can I solve this incomplete graphics on a live DVD?

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, intel-graphics, dvd

I am building a NAS and doing some testing and fiddling using a Ubuntu live DVD (there are no HDDs in there yet).

Unfortunately, when I maximize a window, it won't get updated until I switch to another window and back again, or if I move the mouse over the entire window.

Normal window:

[image: Normal window]

Clutter after maximizing:

[image: Maximized window]

From what I've read on various pages ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638231/how-can-i-switch-graphic-card-acceleration-from-sna-to-uxa), [here (German)](https://axebase.net/blog/2016/06/19/uxa-statt-sna/), [here (German)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/Intel/#Leistungs-oder-Darstellungsprobleme) or [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/IntelPerformance)), I have to switch the graphic acceleration mode to something called UXA to prevent this from happening. Here's how I do it:

```
 sudo -i
 echo -e 'Section "Device"\n\tIdentifier "Intel Graphics"\n\tDriver "i915"\n\tOption "AccelMethod" "uxa"\nEndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf
 echo -e 'Section "Device"\n\tIdentifier "Intel Graphics"\n\tDriver "i915"\n\tOption "AccelMethod" "uxa"\nEndSection' > /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
 pkill X
```

But this does not help. I've also tried to write `xaa` instead of `uxa` or adding `Option "NoAccel" "True"`, this does not help either.

- Do I write to the wrong locations?
- Do I write something wrong?
- Do I have to restart X in another way (many websites say "...then just reboot.", but I cannot do that with a live DVD!)?

*The screenshots have been taken over IPMI.*

---

Updates

- [Raffa](https://askubuntu.com/users/968501/raffa) suggested [booting with `nomodeset`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182211/black-screen-when-i-try-to-install-ubuntu-18-via-usb), this doesn't help.
- [Raffa](https://askubuntu.com/users/968501/raffa) suggested reloading X with `sudo systemctl restart gdm gdm3`, that doesn't help as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black screen when i try to install ubuntu 18 via usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182211/black-screen-when-i-try-to-install-ubuntu-18-via-usb)

Comment: @Raffa: Thank you, but using `nomodeset` boot option doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: To avoid reboot, you could try `sudo systemctl restart gdm gdm3`

Comment: Still the same problem. :(